# React redux: Update nested state's boolean with another nested array of objects by comparing IDs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have following state:

```
merchant: [{
    title: "Setup",
    steps: [
    {id: "provider", done: false}, 
    {id: "api_key", done: false}
    {id: "client", done: false}
    ]
}]
```

and i want to update it with the following dataset

```
merchant: [{
    title: "Setup",
    steps: [
    {id: "provider", done: false}, 
    {id: "api_key", done: true}
    ]
}]
```

So that I end up with the following:

```
merchant: [{
    title: "Setup",
    steps: [
    {id: "provider", done: false}, 
    {id: "api_key", done: true}
    {id: "client", done: false}
    ]
}]
```

What would be the cleanest way to achieve this?

I've done something like this in my reducer, but it seems like a terrible idea based on the output I'm getting.

```
guide_progression: {
    ...state.guide_progression,
    merchant: state.guide_progression.merchant.map(stateGuide =>
        payload.user.guide_progression.merchant.map(userGuide =>
            userGuide.title === stateGuide.title &&
            {
                ...stateGuide,
                steps: stateGuide.steps.map(stateStep =>
                    userGuide.steps.map(userStep =>
                        userStep.id === stateStep.id &&
                        {
                            ...stateStep,
                            done: userStep.done
                        }
                    )
                )
            }
        )
    )
}
```

Really appreciate suggestions for how to solve this. I've been struggling to find a good solution on the web.

Comment: Can you add how does the reducer looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer), It allows you to

> Create the next immutable state tree by simply modifying the current tree

Basically allows you to modify your data while keeping it immutable.

Answer (score 1):

So immer is straight up amazing. Thanks ahmed mahmoud. Here's the solution I ended up with using [immer.js](https://github.com/immerjs/immer)

```
updateMerchantState = produce(state.guide_progression.merchant, draft => {
    payload.user.guide_progression.merchant.map(userGuide => {
        const guideIndex = draft.findIndex(guide => guide.title === userGuide.title)
        if (guideIndex !== -1) {
            userGuide.steps.map(userStep => {
                const stepIndex = draft[guideIndex].steps.findIndex(step => step.id === userStep.id)
                if (stepIndex !== -1) draft[guideIndex].steps[stepIndex].done = userStep.done
            })
        }
    })
})
```